# CloudFormation Custom Resource update with the same parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Is there a way to trigger a Custom Resource lambda without updating parameters? When I update stack without changes it doesn't detect the resource as to be modified. The only solution I'm thinking of is to have a useless parameter with a random value to invoke the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom resource really should be something that only needs to be called when something changes. That's how CloudFormation works. If you really need to force it to "update" then what you are describing would work. Your code doesn't need to care or even know about the extra parameter. As long as the value changes the call to update it will be made.